# While loop not working when boolean changes?

Tags: python, while-loop

The while loop within my code at the bottom does not work, as when a character dies, and finished changes to True, it still keeps looping, does anyone have a fix for this?

I have looked over this many times and can't seem to find a reason why it won't work, it takes a while for the game to finish but when it finally should finish and ask the user if they want to start again it doesn't seem too, it just keeps looping within the while loop.

```
from random import randint
import time
global finished
global att
global character1
global character2
finished = False
att = ["Name", "Skill", "Strength"]
character1 = ["", 10, 10]
character2 = ["", 10, 10]
def block(x):
  time.sleep(x)
  print("====================================")
  time.sleep(1)
def dicethrows():
  global value
  global dice_six_c1
  global dice_six_c2
  dice_twelve = randint(1,12)
  dice_four = randint(1,4)
  dice_six_c1 = randint(1,6)
  dice_six_c2 = randint(1,6)
  value = round(int(dice_twelve) / int(dice_four))
def character_atts():
  dicethrows()
  character1[1] += int(value)
  dicethrows()
  character2[1] += int(value)
  dicethrows()
  character1[2] += int(value)
  dicethrows()
  character2[2] += int(value)
def rules():
  block(1)
  print("Welcome to the Player Game! \n The Rules are!")
  print("1. The Players both get a random skill and strength, if the user does not decide to enter it.")
  print("2. The difference between the Skills and Strengths is found out and divided by 5, to create the modifiers")
  print("3. The Players both roll a 6 sided dice.")
  print("4. The Player who gets the highest roll, gets the modifiers added to their score.")
  print("5. The Player with the lowest roll, gets their score decreased by the modifiers")
  block(20)
def print_c1():
  block(1)
  print("Character One")
  for i in range(0,3):
    print(att[i] + " = "  + str(character1[i]))
def print_c2():
  block(1)
  print("Character Two")
  for i in range(0,3):
    print(att[i] + " = " + str(character2[i]))
def run():
  #rules()
  c1_name = input("Please input a name for character one : ")
  c2_name = input("Please input a name for character two : ")
  character_atts()
  character1[0] = c1_name
  character2[0] = c2_name
  input_own = input("Would you like to input your own stats for the two players? ")
  if input_own.upper() == "YES" or input_own.upper() == "Y":
    character1[1] = int(input("What will " + character1[0] + "'s skill be? "))
    character1[2] = int(input("What will " + character1[0] + "'s strength be? "))
    character2[1] = int(input("What will " + character2[0] + "'s skill be? "))
    character2[2] = int(input("What will " + character2[0] + "'s strength be? "))
  else:
    print("The stats have been randomly generated for you!")
  print_c1()
  print_c2()
##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ABOVE SECTION IS GENERATING CHARACTER SKILL, STRENGTH AND NAMES~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~##
##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~BELOW SECTION IS THE ENCOUTER OF THE PLAYERS IN GAME~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~##

def mods():
  global strength_mod
  global skill_mod
  strength_mod = round(abs(character1[2] - character2[2])/5)
  skill_mod = round(abs(character1[1] - character2[1])/5)
  if skill_mod < 2:
    skill_mod = randint(2,5)
  if strength_mod < 2:
    strength_mod = randint(2,5)

def check():
  if character1[2] <= 0:
    character1[2] = 0
    block(1)
    print(character1[0] + " is dead!!")
    block(1)
    print(character2[0].upper() + " HAS WON WELL DONE!!!!!")
    finished = True
  elif character1[1] < 0:
    character1[1] = 1
  elif character2[2] <= 0:
    character2[2] = 0
    block(1)
    print(character2[0] + " is dead!!")
    block(1)
    print(character1[0].upper() + " HAS WON WELL DONE!!!!!")
    finished = True
  elif character2[1] < 0:
    character2[1] = 1

def encounter():
  while finished == False:
    dicethrows()
    block(1)
    print(character1[0] + " rolled a, " + str(dice_six_c1))
    block(1)
    print(character2[0] + " rolled a, " + str(dice_six_c2))
    block(1)
    print("The Skill Modifier is " + str(skill_mod))
    print("The Strength Modifier is " + str(strength_mod))
    block(1)
    if dice_six_c1 > dice_six_c2:
      print(character1[0] + " rolled HIGHER than " + character2[0])
      print("Their Skill/Strength will now be increased!")
      print(character2[0] + "'s Skill/Strength will now be decreased!")
      character1[1] += skill_mod
      character1[2] += strength_mod
      character2[1] -= skill_mod
      character2[2] -= strength_mod
      block(1)
      print("The new scores are!")
      check()
      print_c1()
      print_c2()
    elif dice_six_c1 < dice_six_c2:
      print(character2[0] + " rolled HIGHER than " + character1[0])
      print("Their Skill/Strength will now be increased!")
      print(character1[0] + "'s Skill/Strength will now be decreased!")
      character2[1] += skill_mod
      character2[2] += strength_mod
      character1[1] -= skill_mod
      character1[2] -= strength_mod
      block(1)
      print("The new scores are!")
      check()
      print_c1()
      print_c2()
    else:
      print("Both rolled the same!! Keep Playing!")
  block(1)
  play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Yes or No - ")
  if play_again.upper() == "YES":
    start()
  else:
    print("Come again soon!")
    block(1)

def start():
  run()
  mods()
  encounter()

start()
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try to use `global finished` before setting `finished = True` in the other methods. Or better: Have `check()` _return_ finished.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't think of it being that simple. It works not again thanks :)

Comment: Your code has a *vast amount* of duplication, which makes it very difficult to find bugs. You should abstract more, e.g. to lists and functions (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You code boils down to this:

```
def check():
    if stuff:
        finished = True

def encounter():
    while finished == False:
        do other stuff
        check()
```

The problem is that while `finished == False` looks for `finished` in the global scope if it can not be found in the local function's scope, `finished = True` will just create a new variable `finished` in the local scope, without affecting the globally defined `finished` used by the other method.

To fix it, you can either tell `check` to use the global `finished` ...

```
def check():
    global finished
    if stuff:
        finished = True
```

... or have `check` return the value of `finished`

```
def check():
    finished = False
    if stuff:
        finished = True
    return finished

def encounter():
    finished = False
    while finished == False:
        do other stuff
        finished = check()
```

Comment: It's better not to use 'global'. Over the time you'll get dependencies you can't manage.

Comment: @Matthias 100% agreed. Making `finished` global is rather a quick-and-dirty fix. In the long run, using proper parameters and return values is much better.

Comment: Now that this is clear I'm going to upvote the answer. :-)